# How to add 0 (zero) when counter insert between 0 to 9 number after than 10, 11, 12...? is can possible?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I am trying to add numbers using **counter-increment** because I want only change the color of the number, that is working fine.
I also want to add 0(Zero) when the number is less than 10 value is this possible? I attached an image of what I want.

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.counter ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.counter ol li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 9px 25px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.counter ol li a {
  color: red;
}

.counter ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: counter(item) ".";
  counter-increment: item;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section class="counter">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: Give me example you understand what i want please give me example.

Comment: How to change only number color any solution for you?

Comment: first understand my question.

Comment: Why this question is duplicate you have answer and solution for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add this to the `ol`:

```
list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.counter ol {
  list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
  color:red;
  counter-reset: item;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.counter ol li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 9px 25px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.counter ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section class="counter">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum, or lips</a></li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: how to change number color only.

Comment: ohh ok. gimme a bit

Comment: This red numbers with leading Zeros??

Comment: Thanks a lost. this is the proper solution.

Comment: It wasn't really easy to understand what you wanted I will edit your question to make it clearer in a bit.